# Set the input size in the table

Tags: html, angular, html-table

I have a table with input-group inside the cells. How do I set the input size to match the size of the cell? I want all the inputs to be as long as the cell size. Below is a portion of the code:

```html
<td>
  <span class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">nato/a a</span>
  </span>
    <input type="text" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </span>
</td>
```

Comment: input {display: block; width: 100%;}

Comment: @Sonia block display will always take the whole width.

Comment: You need "I want all the inputs to be as long as the cell size"

Comment: Did you just add width:100% - that should work

Comment: In this way the "input-group-text" class and the input are shown in two different lines. I want instead that once the "input-group-text" class is over, start the input and continue it until the cell size

Comment: You did not specify this requirement in your request.

Comment: Resolved! Thank you all